# reload/refresh viewcontroller in Xcode 6 with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, opentok

I'm using OpenTok to implement WEBRTC. When i start the current view where you can live chat first time the subscriber view doens't appear, but when i navigate back to another view and then back to the live chat view it works - and this is the issue all time... Is there a way i can refresh or reload my current viewcontroller. I was thinking to make a button in the live chat view which can refresh or reload the view?

```
@IBAction func RefreshButton(sender: AnyObject)
{ 
  //Refresh
}
```

Comment: There is no need refresh a view, you are think to much of web based technologies. Just change what needs to be changed and the view will update.

Comment: Thank for your reply @rckoenes, but what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Wel what do you mean with refresh? For example if you want to change the text in a label you just assign the new string to the text property of that label and you are done. if you have a chat list then this is backed by a data source. So you just add the new message to the data source and reload the table view and the new messages will be added. There is not need to reload a view controller, because you can just change what ever you need to change.

Comment: It is because when I can't connect to stream i need to reload the view - and then it works. the way i reload the view is to go back to another view and then back to the one that connect peer-to-peer video chat - @rckoenes

Comment: Ok. so it seems you just need to recreate the stream. Just `nil` to old stream and create a new one. There is not way to do what you want to do because the concept of reloading in the way you want is not applicable.

Comment: @LocDaiLe can you share the relevant bits of code in your view controller so I can try to see if there are any logical errors? also, it would be helpful if you logged a message in all the OTSessionDelegate/OTPublisherDelegate/OTSubscriberDelegate methods and then shared the logs as well. That would help figure out if there is something being missed.